# How to differentiate between routes with same path but different params in react-router?

Tags: react-router

I have following as part of my react-router configuration:-

```
<Route path="/articles" component={articles}>
          <Route path="/articles/:featureName" component={articleFeatures} />
          <Route path="/articles/:slug" component={articleContent}/>
       </Route>
```

So my links are going to be somewhat like this:-

/articles/sports/ (Feature Name)

/articles/euro-cup-2016 ( Slug)

The content for both the above pages are different. So how should I approach this?

Comment: This is a rather poor router implementation, however it's an interesting problem.

Comment: I have just encountered this problem, I have a two routes, `/trainers/:id` and `trainers/create`. How, did you avoid this clash?